# Hive Insert works fine from Hive CLI but fails from terminal

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I currently have the following situation:

I have a shellscript that creates two tables and then fills one of them with data of the other.

my script looks somewhat like this:

```
    hive -e "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table1 ... ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LOCATION '/user/input/'"
    hive -e "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table2 ... PARTITIONED BY ..."
    hive -e "WITH data AS (SELECT date, ...) FROM data INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table2 PARTITION(part_date) SELECT ... date"
```

and then some more shellscript that selects certain data from table2. I use shellscript because there is some logic that has to be applied before I can do the selects on `table2`.

The script runs without error, the tables are created, `table1` has data in it but `table2`ends up empty. For some reason it works when I use a very small test dataset, but as soon as the dataset becomes bigger (>1GB) `table2` is empty.

If I run the very same commands from Hives CLI manually everything works fine and `table2` has the expected data in it.

Why does this happen, and how could i resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shell script commands must be executed **sequentially** to get data in `table2`.

Try this in your shell script:

```
hive -e "your first query" && 
hive -e "your second query" &&
hive -e "your third query"
```

This should execute your hive queries one after another. (2nd query waits for 1st to finish and 3rd query waits for both 1st and 2nd to finish)